# Custom Styling for Wicegrid 3.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wice-grid

I am using wicegrid 3.0.4 with rails 3. I want to do a custom styling.

I added

```
":html => {:style => 'text-align: center'} or html: {style: 'text-align: center'}"
```

as:

```
g.column :column_name => "Name", :attribute_name => 'name', html: {style: 'text-align: center'}
```

It gives me **"Unknown key: html"**

How can I add custom styles or classes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok got the answer in the docs for wicegrid 3.04
[Wicegrid 3.04 Doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/wice_grid/3.0.4)

Have to write as:

```
g.column :column_name => "Name", :attribute_name => 'name', :td_html_attrs => {:style => 'text-align: right'}
```

Instead of **html:**, need to write **:td_html_attrs**